# Validator for polyglot HTML5

Tags: open-source, html, xml, validation

I want to check if an HTML5 document follows the polyglot markup profile as defined by http://www.w3.org/TR/html-polyglot/. AFAIK first validating as HTML and then as XML doesn’t suffice for this.

Input of the HTML5 document as URL, file upload and/or text input.

It can be anything (a Web app, a library, a desktop client for any OS, …), as long as it is FLOSS.

#### What I tried/know

- http://validator.w3.org/ ([FLOSS](http://validator.w3.org/source/)) doesn’t offer an option for this.
- https://validator.nu/ ([FLOSS](https://github.com/validator/validator)) doesn’t offer an option for this (although it seems to have had it [some time ago](http://intertwingly.net/blog/2009/09/08/First-Polyglot-Validator-Check-Deployed))
- According to its website, [Total Validator](https://www.totalvalidator.com/) supports it ("3rd August 2014 - Total Validator v8.5.0 released: Polyglot Markup updated to 17 July 2014"). They offer a FLOSS Firefox extension, however, you seem to have to install their proprietary client in addition to make it work.